# How to call jasmine-node from ant build.xml

Tags: javascript, node.js, ant, jasmine

I'm trying to use jasmine-node for our testing of js files.  We've written some specs and everything is going smoothly when we test from command line.

However, we're trying to include our tests in our ant build and I've tried several combinations of:

```
    <exec executable="jasmine-node" dir="${dir.src}" verbose="true" failonerror="true" outputproperty="stdout">
        <arg value="--verbose" />
        <arg value="--test-dir" />
        <arg path="${dir.src}" />
    </exec>
```

dir.src is just the base directory where our js files and specs live.  The combinations have been to try and move both values into a line and all three into a line, etc.

As I said, putting "jasmine-node --verbose --test-dir directory" works great in command line.

If anyone can provide any help here, that would be great.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I have this in a trycatch block.  Here's the whole thing:

```
    <trycatch>
        <!-- execute tests -->
        <try>
            <apply executable="jasmine-node" dir="${dir.src}" verbose="true" failonerror="true" outputproperty="stdout">
                <arg value="--verbose" />
                <arg value="--test-dir" />
                <arg path="${dir.src}" />
            </apply>
        </try>
        <catch>
            <property name="error" value="true" />
            <echo message="Jasmine tests failing" />
        </catch>
    </trycatch>
```

Thus, the output in the console is "Jasmine tests failing"

Comment: Please post the result of running your task - does it print an error message?  Fail silently?  etc.

Comment: I guess I should include that I have this in a trycatch block:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After removing the trycatch block, I got an error message saying that you can't have verbose="true" in an exec, though I would swear that I saw that somewhere before.  The verbose was always making it fail, though because I had a catch in there, I wasn't getting a good error message.  I'll be putting the trycatch back in now that I can get the command to run because if the developer building doesn't have jasmine installed, we'll want the build to fail.

Here's my working jasmine-node call.

```
<exec executable="jasmine-node" failonerror="true">
   <arg line="--verbose ${dir.src}" />
</exec>
```

This prints the normal trace stuff that I get when I run jasmine-node in command line, which is exactly what I wanted.

Also, the apply above was just something I was trying to make it work.  What I really wanted was an exec, which is what I had at first.

Answer (score 0):

The trycatch is hiding an error invoking the [apply](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) task. The ANT documentation states:

> At least one fileset or filelist is required, and you must not specify more than one mapper.

Additionally the apply task is generally used to invoke the command against each file in the fileset... I'm not familiar with jasmine-node but I suspect you only want to invoke it once against a directory?

Comment: Actually, apply isn't even right for what I wanted.  I was just giving it a try to see if that would work instead.  Thanks for your answer though!